# В разделе профиля пользователя SO "Все действия" фиксируются не все действия

Tags: поддержка, профиль-участника, голосование

Заметил, что при установке **-1 или +1** к вопросу или ответу, или комментарию в разделе профиля **"Все действия"**, не фиксируется данный момент. Хотя мне бы это очень пригодилось. Наверное и другим тоже. Почему не фиксируется?

Comment: А чем вкладка "Голоса" не устраивает?

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/current?tab=votes не оно разве?

Comment: Да, пардон. Удалить вопрос?

Comment: Хотите, удаляйте. Дело ваше.

Comment: Не обязательно удалять, можно будет в будущем использовать для закрытия дублей)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

На [странице голосов](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/current?tab=votes) всё это можно посмотреть.

> [image: введите сюда описание изображения]